# ggplotly does not respect any calls to remove grid lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridlines, ggplotly

I'm trying to use ggplotly() with ggplot() to create a faceted graph **without gridlines**, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Species) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

p
```

[image]

But when I use ggplotly, the grid lines remain:

```
ggplotly(p)
```

Even when I try to get rid of them using calls to layout:

```
ggplotly(p) %>% layout(xaxis = list(automargin=TRUE, showgrid = F), 
                       yaxis = list(automargin=TRUE, showgrid = F),
                       margin = list(l = 100, b = 100))

ggplotly(p) %>% layout(xaxis = list(automargin=TRUE, gridcolor = "white"), 
                       yaxis = list(automargin=TRUE, gridcolor = "white"),
                       margin = list(l = 100, b = 100))
```

Is this a bug? How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Maybe update the package.

Comment: I've got the dev version of ggplot2 and newest version of plotly.

Comment: I've got `plotly 4.7.1.9000` and `ggplot2 2.2.1.9000`

Comment: Thanks. I'm at `plotly 4.7.1` and `ggplot2 2.2.1.9000`. You've got the dev version of plotly?

Comment: Originally, I couldn't reproduce either. But after being prompted by ggplot2 to update to the dev version, the grid lines are showing like above. It might be a bug, you could [open an issue in Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues).

Comment: Good plan. But should I post about it in the [plotly Github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly) instead of ggplot2?